# Ejecutar una consulta sql desde un formulario Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo que guardar datos en una base desde un formulario hecho en java, la base es en MySQL Server y el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
package vista2; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import datos.*; 

public class Formulario2 extends Frame implements ActionListener{ 
 private static final long serialVersionUID =1;

public Formulario2(){

    this.setTitle("Formulario");
    this.addWindowListener  (new WindowAdapter(){
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
    dispose();
    System.exit(0);
    }
    });
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      Connection conexion = null;
      Statement consulta = null;        

      try{
          conexion = AccesoBD.getConexion(); 
          consulta = (Statement) conexion.createStatement();    

          String Nombre = txtNombre.getText();
          String Direccion = txtDir.getText();
          String Sexo = sexoFem.isSelected()? "Femenino" : "Masculino";
          String Telefono = txtTel.getText();
          String Correo = txtMail.getText();
          String Fecha = txtFecha.getText();
          String Hora = txtHora.getText();
          String primera  = Primera.isSelected()? "SI" : "NO"; 
          String Vuelo = Viaje.isSelected()? "SI" : "NO";
          String hotel = Hotel.isSelected()? "SI" : "NO";


          String sql = "Insert into pasatiempos(Nombre, Direccion, Sexo, Telefono, Correo, Origen, Destino, Fecha, Hora, Primera_Clase, Vuelo_Redondo, Hotel_Incluido) values (" +
                          "'" + Nombre + "'," + Direccion + ",'" +                          
                            Sexo + "'," +
                            Telefono + ",'" + 
                            Correo + "','" + 
                            (String) cmbOrigen.getSelectedItem() + "','" + 
                            (String) cmbDestino.getSelectedItem() + "','" + 
                            Fecha + "','" + 
                            Hora + "','" + 
                            primera + "','" + 
                            Vuelo + "','" + 
                            hotel +"')"; 
          consulta.execute(sql); 

      }
      catch(SQLException|NullPointerException f)
      {
        System.out.println("Error en Consulta");
      }

    }


public static void main(String args[]){
        Formulario2 form = new Formulario2();
        form.setSize(500,250);
        form.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        form.setBackground(Color.green);
        botonOK.addActionListener(form);        

        form.add(big_panel_1);
        form.add(big_panel_2);
        form.add(big_panel_3);      
        form.pack();
        form.setVisible(true);                                                                  
     }
}
```

La conexión se realiza pero no se guardan los datos del formulario en la base, el programa dice: "Conexion satisfactoria" y al oprimir el botón aceptar dice "Error en la consulta".
El driver que se usa está en C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext.
¿Qué se puede hacer para solucionar ese problema?
Omití la parte del código donde se crea la mayor parte del formulario ya que ahí no marca problema.

Comment: Hay que añadir f.getMessage en el println del catch para saber la causa de la excepción. Estaría bien ver cómo está hecha AccesoBD

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a acomodar un poco el código y a hacer ciertas modificaciones.

En primer lugar refactorizaremos el `String` que represents a la consulta en una variable aparte para mejorar la legibilidad de código y la reutilización:

```
static final String INSERT = "INSERT INTO PASATIEMPOS(NOMBRE, DIRECCION, SEXO, TELEFONO, CORREO, ORIGEN, DESTINO, FECHA, HORA, PRIMERA_CLASE, VUELO_REDONDO, HOTEL_INCLUIDO) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Los signos de pregunta son el mecanismo que `PrepraredStatements` posee para realizar `SQLInjection`, esta es la forma de agregar parámetros en las consultas.

Cambiaremos el `Statemens` por un `PreparedStatement` por ende, y el método `createStatement()` por `preparedStatement()`:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conexion.prepareStatement(INSERT)
```

Ahora es donde en nuestra query de insert colocaremos los datos que nosotros deseamos, mediante el seteo de esas variables en la consulta:

```
        stmt.setString(1, txtNombre.getText());
        stmt.setString(2, txtDir.getText());
        stmt.setString(3, sexoFem.isSelected()? "Femenino" : "Masculino");
        stmt.setString(4, txtTel.getText());
        stmt.setString(5, txtMail.getText());
        stmt.setString(6, txtFecha.getText());
        stmt.setString(7, txtHora.getText());
        stmt.setString(8, Primera.isSelected()? "SI" : "NO");
        stmt.setString(9, Viaje.isSelected()? "SI" : "NO");
        stmt.setString(10, Hotel.isSelected()? "SI" : "NO");
```

Estos dos datos te faltaron agregar.

> ```
>        stmt.setString(11,  txtDestino.getText());
>        stmt.setString(12,  txtOrigen.getText());
> ```

Una vez hechos los pasos anteriores podes realizar un  `stmt.executeUpdate();` y listo.